# negate and repeat a atomic group in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to

- match `{{`
- start capture group
- anything thats not `}}`
- end capture
- match `}}`

sample:

```
dummy text
{{ text to be matched }}
more dummy text dummy
dummy {{ foo { bar }} dummy text
dummy text
{{}}}
```

result:

> match 1: `{{ text to be matched }}`
>
> > group 0: `text to be matched`
>
> match 2: `{{ foo { bar }}`
>
> > group 0:`foo { bar`
>
> match 3: `{{}}}`
>
> > group 0: `}`

The problem I'm having is the `not }}` part since Javascript does not have atomic groups.

I cannot negate a non-capturing group and repeat it like this

```
{{                  match {{
    (               capture
        ^(?:}})+    not "}}" 1+ times 
    )               end capture
}}                  match }}
```

This`/{{(.+)}}/` kinda works but only if I don't have line breaks.

Comment: that's why I cant just match `{{` anything then `}}`. It must be `{{` anything but }} then `}}`

Comment: Are you trying to match anything between `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: If `/\{\{(.+)}}/` works but not with line breaks, can you just add an `m` flag, like `/\{\{(.+)}}/m`?

Comment: Doesn't `\{\{(.*?)\}\}` work?

Comment: Kind of works here, doesn't that work like requested? Maybe fiddling with global modifier? https://regex101.com/r/gL9lC3/1

Comment: @AndreiNemes `{{ }}}` matches against `{{ }}`}, it should be capture {{` }`}}.

Comment: @anubhava houston we have a problem :(

Comment: Then try `\{\{(.*)\}\}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fit your requirement, you can use this pattern:

```
{{([^}]*(?:}[^}]+)*}*)}}
```

details:

```
{{
(
    [^}]*         # all that is not a closing bracket
    (?:
        }[^}]+    # a closing bracket followed by at least one other character
    )*
    }*            # eventual closing brackets at the end
)
}}
```

An other way (shorter but less efficient):

```
{{([^]*?)}}(?!})
```

Note: the problem has nothing to do with atomic groups.

Comment: doesn't work for like `{{ foo } bar }}`, its ok `{{ foo }} bar }}` to match just `{{ foo }}` tho

Comment: I think there is a typo in the "shorter" regex? The character class is `[^]` but should probably be `[^}]`

Comment: @jonschlinkert: it isn't, `[^]` means *all characters* (this notation is particular to javascript). In this pattern the main idea is to use a non-greedy quantifier to reach the closing `}}` whatever the content (including lonely `}`). Note that the more standard `[\s\S]` is often used instead of `[^]`, but `[^]` is widely supported in javascript.

Comment: I'm familiar with `[^]` and it's usage, but I thought you were attempting to demonstrate atomic grouping. Your pattern, despite being "non-greedy", will match extra trailing `}`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Here is a full answer, which demonstrates why your regex is incorrect. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67656278/1267639

Comment: @jonschlinkert: extra trailing `}`s are needed see the third example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

No one has demonstrated how you can achieve something like atomic grouping with javascript, including the accepted answer.

We can see how different approaches fair, using the following fixture as an example to match against:

```
const input = `

  {{this}}

  is
  a
  {{sentence}}}}}}}}}}}

`;
```

The regular expression from the accepted answer not only doesn't actually answer the question, but it also will provide invalid matches:

```
const match = input.match(/{{([^]*)}}(?!})/g);
console.log(match);
//=> [ '{{this}}', '{{sentence}}}}}}}}}}}' ]
```

The regex in the accepted answer has a trailing negation clause (`(?!})`), which does nothing at all, since `[^]*?` will match all `}` before reaching the final `}}` defined in the pattern.

A slightly better is to use `[^}]` as I suggested in my comment on the accepted answer:

```
const match = input.match(/{{([^}]*)}}/g);
console.log(match);
//=> [ '{{this}}', '{{sentence}}' ]
```

**Atomic grouping**

As you know, JavaScript regex doesn't have atomic grouping, or even possessive quantifiers, but we can do something kind of similar with lookaheads:

```
const match = input.match(/(?=({{([^]*)}}))\1/g);
console.log(match);
//=> [ '{{this}}', '{{sentence}}' ]
```

Comment: `{{([^}]*?)}}` doesn't match the third example of the question: `{{}}}` => `}`. And, as an aside, why using a non-greedy quantifier since your character class excludes the closing curly bracket?

Comment: "why using a non-greedy quantifier" - you're right, it should be defined without the `?`. It's technically not incorrect but will cause the engine to backtrack making it less efficient.

Comment: "doesn't match the third example of the question" - My interpretation of the question was that the extraneous brace was *not* desired in the third match. Isn't that the point of the atomic group? It says: "anything thats not `}}`", which means it would stop before the first two characters in `}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/
```

The sequence `[\s\S]` is common to match *any* char, including EOLs. Then a lazy quantifier (`+?`) saves the day.

Answer (score 0):

> This/{{(.+)}}/ kinda works but only if I don't have line breaks.

`.` in JS regex doesn't match a newline - you can go with `[\s\S]` instead in your regex.